# disable some custom dates range in a fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I want to block the technician holidays in the calendar, dates are scheduled in the SQL server.

So far I have managed to block the days before the current day.
I wanted to do the same but with the dates of the holidays.

```js
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
      if (moment().diff(date, 'days') > 0) {
        cell.css("background-color", "#F5F5F5");
        $(cell).addClass('disabled');
        
      }
    },
```

I appreciate all the help, thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

This is what I want to do: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xyxeJm

**EDIT 2**

my events code:

```js
<script>
    var url = window.location.href;
    var recortar = url.indexOf("agenda=");
    var tec = url.substr(recortar + 7);
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        pagingType: "simple",
        "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
    });
    
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        } else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });

    <?php
   

    if(isset($_GET['agenda'])){
    $tec = selecttec($_GET['agenda']);
     // curativas
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM npedido WHERE tec1= '$tec' OR tec2= '$tec' OR responsable = '$tec' ";
    $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
// agendamentos
    $sql_agenda = "SELECT * FROM nagenda WHERE tec1= '$tec' OR tec2= '$tec'";
    $stmt_agenda = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql_agenda);
 

?>
    var name = "<?php echo utf8_encode($tec); ?>";
    table.search(name).draw();
    $("#tec_name").val(name);
    $( "#example tr").each(function() {
       if(this.id == tec){
         $(this).addClass('selected');
       }
    });
    var tec = "<?php echo $tec; ?>";
    var events = function () {
        return [

            // curativas agenda 
            <?php while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) { 
                if(strlen(str_replace(' ', '', $row[7])) < 15){ $start=date('h:i Y-m-d',strtotime(str_replace("18", "2018", substr($row[7], -16, 8)))) ;}else{ $start= date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime($row[7])) ; }  
                if(strlen(str_replace(' ', '', $row[7])) < 15){ $end = date('h:i Y-m-d',strtotime(str_replace("18", "2018", substr($row[7], -16, 8)))) ;}else{ $end = date('Y-m-d H:i ',strtotime($row[7])) ; }   
                $start = substr($start,0,10)."T". substr($start,10); 
                $start = str_replace(" ","",$start);
                $end = substr($end,0,10)."T". substr($end,10); 
                $end = str_replace(" ","",$end);
            ?> {
                id: '<?php echo $row[0] ?>',
                title: '<?php echo "Curativa - ".utf8_encode($row[8])."";  ?>',
                start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
                end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
                color: '#0FB1DA',
            },
            <?php }?> 
            // agendamento
            <?php while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt_agenda, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {?> 
                {
                id: '<?php echo $row[0]; ?>',                
                title: '<?php echo "Agendamento - ".utf8_encode($row[4])."";  ?>',
                start: '<?php echo $row[6]; ?>',
                end: '<?php echo $row[7]; ?>',
                dow: [1,4],
                color: '<?php echo $row[10];?>',
            },
            <?php }?> 
        ];
    }
    table.search("").draw();
    <?php }else{?>
    $('#example tbody tr:eq(0)').click();
    <?php }sqlsrv_close($conn);?>
</script>
```

Comment: @Rup added the tag based on the title and code sample - it's https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: DJ you can potentially use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours or perhaps https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events depending on your specific requirements. The various "constraint" options to be found in the documentation might also be of interest to you.

Comment: @ADyson i have read this page you indicate before asking, but i'm not able to implement this because i dont know how to....

Comment: "i have read this page". Which one? There are different options - which one did you want to try? There are examples given in the documentation already. Perhaps if you give us a sample of the dates you want to make unavailable, we can help you write the right code to set it up in fullCalendar. At the moment your question is rather vague unfortuntately.

Comment: @ADyson i he read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours#v2

but i cant implemente this on my code, you whant i add all code on edit?

Comment: @ADyson pls, see this link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xyxeJm

is like this i whant to do

Comment: you mean you only want to highlight those two specific days? In that case it looks like your codepen has already achieved your aim using background events. That's a reasonable way to do it if you have specific times you want to highlight, and those times vary week by week. BusinessHours cannot do that because it doesn't have a time limit - it just repeats the same pattern forever

Comment: @ADyson yes, i whant to highlight those  specific days but from specific days when the technicians were on vacation

i need to create a new function to call those events?

Comment: by "call those events" you mean to fetch them from the server? I don't know if you need a new function, because I don't know how you currently put other events onto the calendar. I don't have any information about how your application works currently. Maybe you need a new function, maybe you can add them to your existing event feed. It's impossible for me to give you specific advice about an application I have never seen.

Comment: @ADyson , i have EDIT, i have add my events code, maby i just query mu vacation table, and implemente the code, right?

Comment: yes you can just make another query and put them into the same list of events, just change the rendering option to "background" for those particular events. I see you are already putting the results of two queries into your list, so you can just add another one for this new set of events.

Comment: @ADyson i will try them i say samting, if worcks i put here the code :D, tanks mate

Comment: yes of course - but if you can fix it, please add it into the Answers section (not into the original question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just added the code and just set the background color, but i whant to disable the click funcion on those days...how i do that?

Code added:

```js
// ferias
            <?php while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt_ferias, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {?> 
                {
                id: '<?php echo $row[0]; ?>',                
                title: '<?php echo "Férias - ".utf8_encode($row[2])."";  ?>',
                start: '<?php echo $row[3]; ?>',
                end: '<?php echo $row[4]; ?>',
                dow: [1,4],
                rendering: 'background',
                color: '#ff9f89'
            },
            <?php }?>
```

Comment: @ADyson , how i disable the click funcion on those dates?

Comment: @ADyson any idea?